# nvidia-smi command in bash vs in terminal for maximum of an array

Tags: bash, shell

Overall goal: I'm trying to assign my python program to the GPU with the most available memory.

Current issue: When I use this command:

`nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv`

I get the following output:

```
memory.free [MiB]
4800 MiB
5332 MiB
5346 MiB
```

Of course, that changes very frequently, so perhaps this is not the best way to accomplish my overall goal. For the moment, I'm trying to use this to figure out which GPU in the set of three has the most free memory. In this case, it's clearly GPU2 (they're labelled 0, 1, 2).

I created a bash script:

```
#/bin/bash

myarr=( $(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv) )
echo $myarr
```

which outputs this to the screen:

```
memory.free
```

It used to output in this format:

```
memory.free [MiB] 4800 MiB 5332 MiB 5346 MiB
```

I then did this ([with thanks to the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566382/maximum-element-and-its-indices-from-an-array-in-shell-script/9566631#9566631)):

```
myarr2=${myarr[2,4,6]}
echo $myarr2
IC=(`tr ' ' '\n' <<<$myarr2 | cat -n | sort -k2,2nr | head -n1`)
echo $IC
Ival=${IC[0]}
Cval=${IC[1]}
echo $Ival $Cval
```

However, it doesn't seem to matter what I do, I always get the index of the maximum to be at position 1. In the example I gave above, this was correct. In general, it is not correct.

The complete script:

```
#/bin/bash

myarr=( $(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv) )
echo $myarr
myarr2=${myarr[2,4,6]}
echo $myarr2
IC=(`tr ' ' '\n' <<<$myarr2 | cat -n | sort -k2,2nr | head -n1`)
echo $IC
Ival=${IC[0]}
Cval=${IC[1]}
echo $Ival $Cval
```

What is wrong with how I'm searching for the position of the maximum?

Comment: `array=( $(...anything...) )` is inherently buggy, as it depends on string-splitting, which happens in conjunction with glob expansion. Anything that advises such a practice should be suspect.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. What should I do instead, though?

Comment: [`readarray -t`/`mapfile -t`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile), or a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)-style loop, generally.

Comment: Though if you're reading in just one line to an array, `read -a` is often the Right Thing as well. (It's also workable when reading a multi-line stream as with `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' lines < <(generate-lines && printf '\0')`, but the caveat is that without that terminating NUL at the end of the input stream, `read` will exit with an error. That can be useful, though, if you want to get feedback on whether the thing generating the input stream completed successfully, and can make the printing of such a NUL byte conditional on same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is verbose, but careful to follow good practices; it can't be mislead by surprising inputs to process local filenames as data (as could happen if a future version of the software had `*`s in the header, for instance), and runs all processing internal to the shell (which can be slower for very large inputs, but for cases where only a small amount of data is being processed -- as here -- will be much faster on account of avoiding process startup overhead for `sort`, `tr`, `cat` or other tools external to the shell).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

max_idx=0
max_mem=0
idx=0

{
  read _;                         # discard first line (header)
  while read -r mem _; do         # for each subsequent line, read first word into mem
    if (( mem > max_mem )); then  # compare against maximum mem value seen
      max_mem=$mem                # ...if greater, then update both that max value
      max_idx=$idx                # ...and our stored index value.
    fi
    ((++idx))
  done
} < <(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv)

echo "Maximum memory seen is $max_mem, at processor $idx"
```

If I define `nvidia-smi` as follows (note that due to the `-` in the name, this definition isn't portable to all versions of bash):

```
nvidia-smi() { printf '%s\n' 'memory.free [MiB]' '4800 MiB' '5332 MiB' '5346 MiB'; }
```

...this emits as output:

```
Maximum memory seen is 5346, at processor 3
```