# Bash: how to send my own custom function through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh-tunnel

My goal is to do the following:

1) Check how much memory is being used by each GPU on a specific server. I accomplish this with `(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv)`.

2) Find the GPU with the maximum free memory. I accomplish this with `my_cmd()`. It works for the remote server I am currently logged into.

3) If the maximum free memory on the remote server I'm logged into is less than 1000 MiB, SSH into each other GPU server in the cluster to find the maximum free memory available. These servers are labelled according to `to_check`.

My current issue:

The code below works when `scriptuse` is given the `cd` command, etc.

The code below fails when `scriptuse` is given `mycmd`. It gives me the error:

`bash: my_cmd: command not found`.

Now, I think there's more than one problem here. First, I think I'm not providing `my_cmd` properly to the `ssh` command. Second, when I use `my_cmd`, I don't think I'm successfully sshing into the other servers.

Can anyone point out what is wrong and how to fix it?

The complete bash script is below.

```
#/bin/bash

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313313/nvidia-smi-command-in-bash-vs-in-terminal-for-maximum-of-an-array/45313404#45313404

my_cmd()
{
max_idx=0
max_mem=0
idx=0
{
  read _;                         # discard first line (header)
  while read -r mem _; do         # for each subsequent line, read first word into mem
    if (( mem > max_mem )); then  # compare against maximum mem value seen
      max_mem=$mem                # ...if greater, then update both that max value
      max_idx=$idx                # ...and our stored index value.
    fi
    ((++idx))
  done
} < <(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv)
echo "Maximum memory seen is $max_mem, at processor $idx"
}

tocheck=('4' '5' '6' '7' '8')  #The GPUs to check
it1=1

#scriptuse="my_cmd" 
scriptuse= "cd ~/spatial; pwd; echo $gpuval"

while [ $it1 -lt ${#tocheck[@]} ] ; do #While we stil don't have enough free memory
        echo $it1 
        gpuval=${tocheck[$it1]}
        ssh gpu${gpuval} "${scriptuse}"
        it1=$[it1+1]
done
```

### EDIT

Thank you very much for the help, but my problem is not yet solved. I have done this:

1) Remove `my_cmd` from my bash script. It now looks like this:

```
#/bin/bash

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313313/nvidia-smi-command-in-bash-vs-in-terminal-for-maximum-of-an-array/45313404#45313404

tocheck=('4' '5' '6' '7' '8')  #The GPUs to check
it1=1

scriptuse= "cd ~/spatial; echo $gpuval"

while [ $it1 -lt ${#tocheck[@]} ] ; do #While we stil don't have enough free memory
        echo $it1 
        gpuval=${tocheck[$it1]}
        ssh gpu${gpuval} "${scriptuse}" /my_script.sh
        it1=$[it1+1]
done
```

2) Create a separate bash script called `my_script.sh` that contains `my_cmd`:

```
#/bin/bash

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313313/nvidia-smi-command-in-bash-vs-in-terminal-for-maximum-of-an-array/45313404#45313404
max_idx=0
max_mem=0
idx=0
{
  read _;                         # discard first line (header)
  while read -r mem _; do         # for each subsequent line, read first word into mem
    if (( mem > max_mem )); then  # compare against maximum mem value seen
      max_mem=$mem                # ...if greater, then update both that max value
      max_idx=$idx                # ...and our stored index value.
    fi
    ((++idx))
  done
} < <(nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv)
echo "Maximum memory seen is $max_mem, at processor $idx"
```

3) Ran `chmod` to ensure both files can be run.

4) Ensured both files exist on all GPUs in the cluster (they have a common storage).

5) Ran `./test_run`, which is the bash script from step 1.

I get the error:

```
./test_run.sh: line 8: cd ~/spatial; echo : No such file or directory
1
bash: /my_script.sh: No such file or directory
2
bash: /my_script.sh: No such file or directory
3
bash: /my_script.sh: No such file or directory
4
bash: /my_script.sh: No such file or directory
```

**EDIT: The final solution**

Thanks to the accepted answer below and the discussion in the comments, here's what ended up working:

1) Leave `my_script` as it is in the previous edit.

2) The file `test_run` should look like this:

```
#/bin/bash

tocheck=('4' '5' '6' '7' '8')  #The GPUs to check
it1=1

while [ $it1 -lt ${#tocheck[@]} ] ; do #While we still don't have enough free memory
        echo $it1 
        gpuval=${tocheck[$it1]}
        ssh gpu${gpuval} ~/spatial/my_script.sh
        it1=$[it1+1]
done
```

I think the reason this works is that all of the GPUs on the cluster have a common storage, so they all have access to `/user/spatial`.

Comment: This seems really roundabout - why not put the functions you need in a file and `scp` the file to the remote server? You can check the file into a VCS (Git, Mercurial) instead if you're worried about them getting out of sync.

Comment: "*First, I think I'm not providing my_cmd properly to the ssh command.*" - well, more accurately you're not providing it at all - `ssh hostname foo` tells the remote server to invoke a `foo` command in *its* shell, it has no awareness of your shell or the functions defined in it.

Comment: @dim0414 I'm sorry but I don't understand your suggestion. The `ssh gpu${gpuval} "${scriptuse}"` part seems to be working when I use `scriptuse` as defined outside of the comment. But then when I comment it out, and use the other `scriptuse` ("my_cmd"), it doesn't work.

Comment: Right, because the remote server has a `cd` command. It has no idea what `my_cmd` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment your script is running in (your shell) is totally unrelated to the environment the remote host is running in (the remote shell). If you define a function `my_cmd` in your shell it will not be transmitted across the wire to the remote host's shell.

Try a simpler example:

```
$ foo() { echo foo; }
$ foo
foo
$ ssh remote-host foo
bash: foo: command not found
```

This simply isn't how SSH, Bash, and Linux/POSIX are designed. Now, `ssh` *does* update some parts of the remote environment (as detailed in [`man ssh`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh#ENVIRONMENT)), but this is limited to certain environment variables, not functions.

Notably, the remote shell might not even be the same type of shell as your (e.g. yours might be Bash, but the remote shell might be Zsh), so it's not possible generally to transmit shell functions across `ssh`.

---

A much simpler and more reliable option is to create a shell script (rather than a function) that you intend to be run on the remote shell, and ensure that script exists on the remote machine. For example:

```
# Copy the script to the remote host's /tmp directory
scp my_cmd.sh remote-host:/tmp
# Invoke the script on the remote host
$ ssh remote-host /tmp/my_cmd.sh
```

---

**Edit:**

> ```
> ./test_run.sh: line 8: cd ~/spatial; echo : No such file or directory
> ```

Are you sure `~/spatial` exists on the remote host?

> ```
> bash: /my_script.sh: No such file or directory
> ```

Are you sure `/my_script.sh` exists on the remote host?

Again, your remote host is a wholly different environment. Just because a file or directory exists on your local machine doesn't mean it exists on the remote host unless you put it there.

Try `ssh [remote-host] 'ls ~'` and `ssh [remote-host] 'ls /'` - I bet you'll see the directory and file don't exist.

Comment: Thank you @dimo414, please see my edited version. The problem has not yet been solved.

Comment: @StatsSorceress I don't think you've put the files on the remote hosts. See my edit.

Comment: Hi @dimo414. The cluster has a central storage. All of my files are visible from each GPU in the cluster. So for example: `user@GPU4:~/spatial$ ls ` gives
`my_script.sh  test_run.sh`
And so does this: `user@GPU1:~/spatial$ ls`
`my_script.sh  test_run.sh`

Comment: What directory are you `ls`-ing there? Presumably `~`, which is *not* `/`. You're running `/my_script.sh` but if you've put the script in the current directory it's `./my_script.sh` or `~/my_script.sh`. And I don't see a `spatial` directory in that output.

Comment: I'm `ls` ing the `spatial` directory. I tried both, and interestingly it seems I'm not `cd`ing after all. The second one, '~/my_script.sh` gave me this: `bash: /user/my_script.sh: No such file or directory`, but it should be `/user/spatial/`, not just `/user`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah - finally got it to work! Needed to specify the full path to the file on the remote server. Since the storage directory is the same for all GPUs on the cluster, it's the same for all GPUs. I'll accept your answer, because it got me there, and I'll edit my question to include exactly what I ended up doing. Thank you again!

Comment: Right; you were specifying nonexistent paths, hence the "No such file" errors. Relative paths would work too, as long as you specify the path *relative to the directory you're running in*. As I said above, *if* the script is in `~` then `~/my_script.sh` would work. Since it wasn't located there then of course you'd get a "No such file" error trying to invoke such a path.